# Dart won't initialize static list until it is called

Tags: dart

I have a static field:

```dart
static final List<Provider> _providers = [
    ESVAPI()
  ];
```

And the objects inside of it are constructed (with a call to the super class) to add themselves to other lists:

```dart
Provider(this.name, this.requiresKey, this._versions) {
   Provider._foo.add(name);
}
```

When I try referencing the list `foo` within the class, before I reference the variable the objects are not initialized. For example:

```dart
  static final List<Provider> _providers = [
    ESVAPI(),
  ];
  static final _foo = <String>[];
  static final name = _foo[0];
```

The variable `name` will be null since the items in the list are not yet initialized. The `ESVAPI` object will not be initialized until I reference `_providers`. Even if I were to reference it, the variable `name` will remain null since it was already constructed with the null value.

Considering the variables are final and I know how many classes there are, it would not be difficult to simply type in the needed values, but being able to immediately initialize a list and all the values inside of it would prove useful in the future for different use cases. Is there any way to initialize the values in the static list when the the list is first instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, static fields are lazily evaluated in dart. So there is no way to bypass this, except to "touch" the field.

Comment: Yea that's what I'm thinking. It's probably for efficiency; which makes sense. Thanks